# Why does dhclient only work if its not specified in /etc/rc.conf

Tags: dhcp, freebsd

I have just set up a FreeBSD 8.1 in a VM and am trying to get it to do DHCP automatically.  Right now, if I leave `/etc/rc.conf` like so:

```
#ifconfig_de0="DHCP"
```

then I can do `dhclient de0` and it gets an IP instantly.

If I remove the comment so that DHCP is supposedly automatic, then `dhclient de0` never gets an address (and it doesn't happen automatically either)

I get `DHCPREQUEST on de0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67`

Nothing else changes, what am I doing wrong?

I've also tried using sysinstall, but I have found no way to get it to write the changes to the files once I make them.....

==== Edit

Hoping to save someone else the time I spent on this, here is my rc.conf:

```
# -- sysinstall generated deltas -- # Mon Dec  6 11:51:13 2010
# -- sysinstall generated deltas -- # Wed Dec  8 08:28:27 2010
# Created: Mon Dec  6 11:51:13 2010
# Enable network daemons for user convenience.
# Please make all changes to this file, not to /etc/defaults/rc.conf.
# This file now contains just the overrides from /etc/defaults/rc.conf.
#REMOVED: inetd_enable="YES"
hostname="pfsensedev.intomec.com"
#ifconfig_de0="DHCP"
inetd_enable="NO"
sshd_enable="YES"
```

I found that I had to comment out the ifconfig_de0 line if I wanted to get an IP address assigned.  If I left it in rc.conf, it was impossible to get an IP address via dhclient.

Putting the lines into /etc/rc.local did the trick

```
dhclient de0
```

I'm running this on a MS Virtual PC VM under Win7x64 (already had it loaded for XP Mode).

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: The rc.conf file is only read during boot, or by manually restarting the netif stack with `/etc/rc.d/netif restart`; are you doing either of those after modifying the file?

Comment: Do you have any other lines that start with ifconfig_de0, or any configuration options for DHCP in rc.conf (might be easiest to simply post the whole file)? What version are you running and how was it installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it right. If it doesn't work in your case, you could also use `/etc/rc.local`. Put the command `dhclient de0` into this file and it will be run upon system start.

Comment: Since 6.0 the use of rc.local is strongly discouraged, and especially in cases where there's a knob in rc.conf for the same functionality. This would work however.

Comment: rc.local does fix the problem, even if strongly discouraged.  I even punted and reloaded the OS to make sure I hadn't messed up rc.conf somehow, but it looks and acts the same either way.